# Emacs eshell 'ulimit' command

Tags: emacs, ulimit, eshell

why i could not find ulimit command in esehll mode
but M-x ansi-term had not this problem.
how could i fix it.

like this:

~ $ ulimit -c
ulimit: command not found
~ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ulimit is a shell-builtin and not a binary. ansi-term uses your normal shell (bash, zsh, or whatever you are using) while eshell is a shell of its own, and it does not seem to implement ulimit.

Comment: Thank you Dominikh.I know how workaroud it               
                                                                     in the eshell mode runing a normal shell